# Line chart slice to calculate difference (actual and percentage) between two points

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization

I have an annotated line chart built successfully from a CSV file using google annotation charts. (Thanks Whitehat for your help).

I have looked unsuccessfully through the google chart examples to find a way of grabbing a slice of the line chart so as to then perform some calculations between the two points e.g. difference and percentage difference. There may be further calculations I wish to do but these two are enough for the moment.

Essentially I am trying to build a feature like Google's stock chart

[image]

Code so far:

```
<html>

  <head>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-csv/0.71/jquery.csv-0.71.min.js"></script>

                <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>

    <script type='text/javascript'>





// load google charts

google.charts.load('current', {

  packages: ['annotationchart']

}).then(function () {

  // declare data variable

  var arrayData;



  // get csv data

  $.get('test.csv', function(csvString) {

    // get csv data success, convert to an array, draw chart

    arrayData = $.csv.toArrays(csvString, {onParseValue: $.csv.hooks.castToScalar});

    drawChart(arrayData);

  })

});



// draw chart

function drawChart(arrayData) {

  // convert string in first column to a date

  arrayData = arrayData.map(function (row) {

    return [new Date(row[0]),row[1],row[2]];

  });



  // create google data table, chart, and options

  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(arrayData);

  var chart = new google.visualization.AnnotationChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

  var options = {

    displayAnnotations: true

  };



  // draw chart

  chart.draw(data, options);

}             



    </script>

  </head>



  <body>

    <div id='chart_div' style='width: 1200x; height: 700px;'></div>

  </body>

</html>
```

Any ideas how I can go about doing this?

Comment: will you please clarify? --> _grab a slice of the line chart_ -- google's data table has a method for [getFilteredRows](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#DataTable_getFilteredRows) which you can use to retrieve row indexes that meet certain criteria...

Comment: By slice I meant clicking on one point and dragging across to the next. If you take google stock chart for example, click any point on the graph and then drag back/forwards on the graph a label will tell you the actual and percentage differences between the two points   https://www.google.com/search?q=google+stock+price&rlz=1C1GCEU_enNZ832NZ832&oq=google+stock+price&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l2j69i60l2j0.2921j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Perhaps the term "slicing" isn't accurate here. I'll have a play with getFilteredRows

Comment: use [the `'select'` event](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/events#the-select-event) to know when the user has selected a point

Comment: I've been playing around with the select event and can successfully pick one point. I'm working on figuring out how to select a point and then drag across to the next point. I am using an example you posted a while back for selecting multiple points on a scatter plot. I'll see how I go

Comment: Still no luck. Example I've got only allows selection of one point. Don't know how to select two points. Do I need to use mouse handling events? Mouse down and then mouse up as I drag from one point to another?

Answer (score 1):

you could use mouse events to allow the user to draw a selection on the chart.

given the coordinates of the selection,
use [chart methods](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#methods) `getChartLayoutInterface` & `getHAxisValue`,
to determine the range of values the user selected.

see following working snippet,
click the chart and hold the mouse, then drag to draw the selection.
when the mouse is let go, the values selected will be displayed.

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['controls', 'corechart']
}).then(function () {
  // build data table
  var oneDay = (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  var dateEnd = new Date();
  var dateStart = new Date(dateEnd.getTime() - (oneDay * 365.25));
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('date', 'Date');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Y');
  for (var i = dateStart.getTime(); i <= dateEnd.getTime(); i = i + oneDay) {
    var direction = (i % 2 === 0) ? 1 : -1;
    var rowDate = new Date(i);
    data.addRow([rowDate, rowDate.getFullYear() + (rowDate.getDate() * direction)]);
  }

  // chart options
  var options = {
    chartArea: {
      height: '100%',
      width: '100%',
      top: 24,
      left: 60,
      right: 16,
      bottom: 60
    },
    hAxis: {
      format: 'MMM-yyyy'
    },
    height: '100%',
    legend: {
      position: 'top'
    },
    width: '100%'
  };

  // create chart and elements
  var container = document.getElementById('chart');
  var values = document.getElementById('values');
  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(container);

  // wait until chart is ready
  google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    // initialize variables
    var chartLayout = chart.getChartLayoutInterface();
    var chartArea = chartLayout.getChartAreaBoundingBox();
    var chartBounds = container.getBoundingClientRect();
    var select = document.getElementById('select');
    var x1 = 0;
    var y1 = 0;
    var x2 = 0;
    var y2 = 0;
    var x3 = 0;
    var y3 = 0;
    var x4 = 0;
    var y4 = 0;

    // listen for mouse events
    window.addEventListener('mousedown', function (e) {
      select.className = '';
      x1 = e.pageX;
      y1 = e.pageY;
      reCalc();
    });
    window.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
      if (select.className === '') {
        x2 = e.pageX;
        y2 = e.pageY;
        reCalc();
      }
    });
    window.addEventListener('mouseup', function (e) {
      select.className = 'static';
      selectPoints();
    });

    // show user selection
    function reCalc() {
      x3 = Math.min(x1,x2);
      x4 = Math.max(x1,x2);
      y3 = Math.min(y1,y2);
      y4 = Math.max(y1,y2);
      select.style.left = x3 + 'px';
      select.style.width = x4 - x3 + 'px';
      select.style.top = (chartBounds.top + chartArea.top + window.pageYOffset) + 'px';
      select.style.height = (chartArea.height + window.pageYOffset) + 'px';
    }

    // show values from selection
    function selectPoints() {
      if ((((chartBounds.left + window.pageXOffset) <= x3) &&
           ((chartBounds.left + chartBounds.width + window.pageXOffset) >= x4)) &&
          (((chartBounds.top + window.pageYOffset) <= y3) &&
           ((chartBounds.top + chartBounds.height + window.pageYOffset) >= y4))) {
        var rows = data.getFilteredRows([{
          column: 0,
          minValue: chartLayout.getHAxisValue(x3),
          maxValue: chartLayout.getHAxisValue(x4)
        }]);

        values.innerHTML = '';
        rows.forEach(function (index) {
          var value = values.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
          value.innerHTML = data.getFormattedValue(index, 0) + ': ' + data.getFormattedValue(index, 1);
        });
      }
    }
  });

  // draw chart
  chart.draw(data, options);
});
```

```css
#select {
  background-color: #3366cc;
  border: 1px solid #3366cc;
  opacity: 0.2;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1000;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div class="hidden" id="select"></div>
<div id="chart"></div>
<div id="values"></div>
```

Comment: Hi WhiteHat, I was able to get a solution for my question but only using HighChart. Please have a look at this https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/745fL9a0. Is it possible to do something like this with google charts?

Comment: yes, google has a [range filter](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/controls#chartrangefilter) control, which didn't come to mind when answering...